# jquery siblings() without selector not working

Tags: jquery, html, selector

Simple table:

```
    <table class="schedules">
        <th colspan="2">Saved Schedules</th>
        <tr>
            <td>Winter 2011 </td>           
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Winter 2011 (2) </td>           
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>May Term 2011 </td>         
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fall Term 2011</td>         
        </tr>       
    </table>
```

Jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".schedules td").click(function(){
                $(this).css("background-color","blue")
                $(this).siblings().css("background-color","white");         
            });
        });     
    </script>
```

This should toggle the selected cell to background-color:blue and the siblings to background-color:white, but when I click each cell just changes to background-color:blue and the others don't change at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `<td>`'s are cousins, not siblings. The td's parents (the `<tr>`'s) are siblings. You could modify the jquery like this...

http://jsfiddle.net/superuntitled/fb4g7/

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".schedules tr").click(function(){
            $(this).find('td').css("background-color","blue")
            $(this).siblings().find('td').css("background-color","white");         
        });
    });
```

Comment: Nice! You should edit your post to contain the jquery you came up with. I like this one because it fits the way I was thinking about the problem!

Answer (score 2):

The other `<td>` elements are not siblings.

You can traverse up to a common ancestor with the [`closest()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method, then [`find()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/)  the `<td>` elements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".schedules td").click(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","blue")
               .closest('table').find('td').not(this).css("background-color","white");         
    });
});
```

Or you can traverse up to the `<tr>`, and use `.siblings()` on that followed by the [`children()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".schedules td").click(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","blue")
               .parent().siblings().children('td').css("background-color","white");         
    });
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

Or the most efficient would be to cache your `<td>` elements, and exclude the current.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tds = $(".schedules td").click(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","blue");
        tds.not(this).css("background-color","white");         
    });
});
```

Eliminates the DOM selection completely inside the handler.

Generally you should try to cache selections instead of repeating them.

Comment: haha duh. I was thinking logical siblings not according to the dom! Thanks :)